# Unhandled Rejection ReferenceError: Cannot access 'message' before initialization

Tags: discord.js

I'm writing a discord.js bot and it gives me error listed in title. I'm using discord.js 11
This piece of code gives user role when they add a role.

```
client.on('raw', async event => {
if (!events.hasOwnProperty(event.t)) return;

const {
    d: data
} = event;
const user = client.users.get(data.user_id);
const channel = client.channels.get(data.channel_id);

const message = message.channel.fetchMessage(data.message_id);
const member = message.guild.members.get(user.id);

const emojiKey = (data.emoji.id) ? `${data.emoji.name}:${data.emoji.id}` : data.emoji.name;
let reaction = message.reactions.get(emojiKey);

if (!reaction) {
    // Create an object that can be passed through the event like normal
    const emoji = new Emoji(client.guilds.get(data.guild_id), data.emoji);
    reaction = new MessageReaction(message, emoji, 1, data.user_id === client.user.id);
}

let embedFooterText;
if (message.embeds[0]) embedFooterText = message.embeds[0].footer.text;

if (
    (message.author.id === client.user.id) && (message.content !== CONFIG.initialMessage ||
        (message.embeds[0] && (embedFooterText !== CONFIG.embedFooter)))
) {

    if (!CONFIG.embed && (message.embeds.length < 1)) {
        const re = `\\*\\*"(.+)?(?="\\*\\*)`;
        const role = message.content.match(re)[1];

        if (member.id !== client.user.id) {
            const guildRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === role);
            if (event.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD") member.addRole(guildRole.id);
            else if (event.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE") member.removeRole(guildRole.id);
        }
    } else if (CONFIG.embed && (message.embeds.length >= 1)) {
        const fields = message.embeds[0].fields;

        for (const {
                name,
                value
            } of fields) {
            if (member.id !== client.user.id) {
                const guildRole = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === value);
                if ((name === reaction.emoji.name) || (name === reaction.emoji.toString())) {
                    if (event.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD") member.addRole(guildRole.id);
                    else if (event.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE") member.removeRole(guildRole.id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

The error says that this line is the fault: `const message = message.channel.fetchMessage(data.message_id);`
but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your problem is this.

Basically, you're trying to declare a variable with the same variable that doesn't exist yet.

Try changing this line: `const message = message.channel.fetchMessage(data.message_id);`
to this: `const message = channel.fetchMessage(data.message_id);`

Hope this helps.

P.S. Looks like you're using discord.js v11, I recommend upgrading to v12 because v11 does not support the new API that is coming out in October.